# Jasper Report Subreports is not showing data

Tags: jasper-reports, subreport

I have a jasper report with 2 subreports. When I execute the report from a Java program it shows up but with empty subreports. Here is my report:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="report3" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="535" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="b0b596c0-43c5-4c85-8e81-e92b916f7bb5">
    <property name="ireport.zoom" value="1.0"/>
    <property name="ireport.x" value="0"/>
    <property name="ireport.y" value="0"/>
    <style name="Title" fontName="Arial" fontSize="26" isBold="true" pdfFontName="Helvetica-Bold"/>
    <style name="SubTitle" forecolor="#666666" fontName="Arial" fontSize="18"/>
    <style name="Column header" forecolor="#666666" fontName="Arial" fontSize="12" isBold="true"/>
    <style name="Detail" fontName="Arial" fontSize="12"/>
    <parameter name="customer_id" class="java.lang.Integer">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="SUBREPORT_DIR" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA["reports/"]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="order_date" class="java.util.Date">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="title" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[SELECT
     customer.`name` AS customer_name
FROM
     `customer` customer
where id=$P{customer_id}]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="customer_name" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <title>
        <band height="95" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement style="SubTitle" x="102" y="65" width="54" height="20" uuid="57dccf10-55f0-4d62-b391-c0a835ea062b"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right">
                    <font fontName="Serif" size="14"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[التاريخ:]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement style="Column header" x="478" y="65" width="77" height="20" uuid="cc412a3e-0e4f-4868-9ea3-75c9e2f08bd3"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right">
                    <font fontName="Serif" size="14" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[المطلوب من:]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField>
                <reportElement style="Detail" x="229" y="65" width="249" height="20" uuid="28bb50ef-8818-45d6-97c5-6608cc747060"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right">
                    <font fontName="Serif" size="14"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{customer_name}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement x="3" y="65" width="100" height="20" uuid="32a97ac4-8aab-4167-99d6-1c3489f83db2"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Serif" size="14"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{order_date}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement style="Title" x="142" y="16" width="265" height="33" uuid="dc9fed5e-e03c-475c-bd2b-1b351c318192"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Serif" size="26" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{title}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </title>
    <pageHeader>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </pageHeader>
    <columnHeader>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </columnHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="195" splitType="Stretch">
            <subreport>
                <reportElement x="2" y="1" width="553" height="109" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" isPrintInFirstWholeBand="true" uuid="e9c0b556-6457-4dc8-9064-b9bf8a280490"/>
                <subreportParameter name="title">
                    <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{title}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                </subreportParameter>
                <subreportParameter name="REPORT_CONNECTION">
                    <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                </subreportParameter>
                <subreportParameter name="order_date">
                    <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{order_date}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                </subreportParameter>
                <subreportParameter name="cust_id">
                    <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{customer_id}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                </subreportParameter>
                <subreportParameter name="customer_id">
                    <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{customer_id}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                </subreportParameter>
                <connectionExpression><![CDATA[java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/metal?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8","root", "")]]></connectionExpression>
                <subreportExpression><![CDATA[$P{SUBREPORT_DIR} + "orders.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
            </subreport>
            <subreport>
                <reportElement positionType="Float" x="2" y="109" width="554" height="86" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" isPrintInFirstWholeBand="true" uuid="bca2d802-6eee-43c3-adb9-443cb2b11cd9"/>
                <subreportParameter name="SUBREPORT_DIR">
                    <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{SUBREPORT_DIR}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                </subreportParameter>
                <subreportParameter name="title">
                    <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{title}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                </subreportParameter>
                <subreportParameter name="order_date">
                    <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{order_date}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                </subreportParameter>
                <subreportParameter name="cust_id">
                    <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{customer_id}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                </subreportParameter>
                <subreportParameter name="customer_id">
                    <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{customer_id}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                </subreportParameter>
                <connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>
                <subreportExpression><![CDATA[$P{SUBREPORT_DIR} + "order_additions.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
            </subreport>
        </band>
    </detail>
    <columnFooter>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </columnFooter>
    <pageFooter>
        <band height="30" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement style="Column header" x="435" y="9" width="80" height="20" uuid="aba41e81-e785-4bdf-bbaa-1d8c3be8b391"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right">
                    <font size="10" isBold="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Page "+$V{PAGE_NUMBER}+" of"]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField evaluationTime="Report">
                <reportElement style="Column header" x="515" y="9" width="40" height="20" uuid="ef8ba53a-7da2-4fb1-a438-d1b0e2eb3a25"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="10" isBold="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[" " + $V{PAGE_NUMBER}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField pattern="EEEEE dd MMMMM yyyy">
                <reportElement style="Column header" x="2" y="9" width="197" height="20" uuid="84337f90-d94a-4f7a-a376-18bf89cc1de9"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="10" isBold="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[new java.util.Date()]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </pageFooter>
    <summary>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </summary>
</jasperReport>
```

I guess my subreport doesn't get the connection from the parent report. How to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second subreport that you include is the correct way to pass the connection

```
 <connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>
```

So you need to check

```
$P{SUBREPORT_DIR} + "order_additions.jasper", points to an actually report
```

and that the query in `order_additions.jasper` produce result.